# Advice not being called

Tags: java, spring-aop

i have a simple spring application with the following code :

**Aspect Loader Class** 
    package com.ishan.spring.aspectLoader;

```
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.ishan.spring.services.ShapeService;

public class AspectLoader {

public static void main(String a[]){

    AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");

    context.registerShutdownHook();

    ShapeService service = (ShapeService) context.getBean("shapeService");
    service.draw();

}
```

}

**ShapeService Class**

```
package com.ishan.spring.services;

import com.ishan.spring.interfaces.Shape;

public class ShapeService {

public Shape getShape() {
    return shape;
}

public void setShape(Shape shape) {
    this.shape = shape;
}

public String draw1(){
    System.out.println("String draw called");
    this.shape.draw();
    return "drawn";
}

 public int draw(){
     System.out.println("int draw called");
     draw1();
    return 1;
 }

private Shape shape;

}
```

**Circle class**

```
package com.ishan.spring.impl;

import com.ishan.spring.interfaces.Shape;

public class Circle implements Shape{

private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public void draw() {
    System.out.println("Circle drawn");

}
```

}

**Shape interface**

```
package com.ishan.spring.interfaces;

public interface Shape {

public void draw();
}
```

**Logging aspect**

```
package com.ishan.spring.aspects;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

@Before("execution(public * draw*(..))")
public void logBefore(){
    System.out.println("Advice run before method call");
}

}
```

**spring.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
default-autowire="byName"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop      http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

<bean id="circle" class="com.ishan.spring.impl.Circle">
    <property name="name" value="myCircle"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="triangle" class="com.ishan.spring.impl.Triangle">
    <property name="name" value="myTriangle"></property>
</bean> 

<bean id="shapeService" class="com.ishan.spring.services.ShapeService">
    <property name="shape" ref="triangle"></property>
</bean> 

    <bean id="logAspect" class="com.ishan.spring.aspects.LoggingAspect"/>

</beans>
```

The problem is I cannot get to run my advice before the draw1() method of the shapeservice class . I am not able to figure out the problem in my wildcard expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Your wildcard expression is good.

The reason why the aspect doesn't fire on `draw1()` method is because it is invoked from `draw()`; which is within same bean i.e. simple java method invocation.

If `draw1()` is invoked from other spring bean (*or just like `draw()` is invoked*) the aspect will fire for sure.

To see it for yourself try below

```
ShapeService service = (ShapeService) context.getBean("shapeService");
service.draw1();
```